# An error occurred when I was running "ionic cordova platform add ios"

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

An error occurred when I was running `ionic cordova platform add ios`.It noticed me with the information

> [ERROR] Cordova encountered an error.
>           You may get more insight by running the Cordova command above directly.
>
> [ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova platform add ios
>   --save (exit code 1):

```
    Using cordova-fetch for cordova-ios@^4.4.0
    Adding zone.js project...
    Error: Your zone.js platform does not have Api.js”
```

I had tried to update the version of ionic / cordova and also reinstalled node.js and npm.But It still no worked.

Who can tell me how to resolve this problem。Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your iOS platform seems to corrupted. Please remove and re-add the platform to resolve the issue using following commands:

> cordova platform rm ios
>
> cordova platform add ios

### EDIT

If it happens when you try `ionic cordova run/build android` it will work with the same steps

> cordova platform rm android
>
> cordova platform add android

Then run `ionic cordova run/build android` and it will work.

Comment: I had tried to use the commands ,but it still no worked.It noticed me      Error: Failed to fetch platform cordova-ios@latest
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Failed to get absolute path to installed module                                            any idea?

Comment: @KingsleyTong could you try creating a new project and add iOS platform so that we can isolate problem

Comment: Thank you for your answer . I added --nofetch at second commands.And this problem had been resoleved by using the commands which you provided .

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Thanks for the info. Should be helpful for someone with the same problem. Cheers

Comment: @Gandhi I've edited your answer if it's not a bother for you ;)

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Not at all. As long as its useful for others, you are welcome to do that. Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Gandhi, it didn't work for iOS. i am getting error as :  An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

Comment: @ArshadShaik Please be more specific with the error before downvoting

Answer (score 4):

This problem had been resolved by using commands

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add ios --nofetch
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are on **linux or mac** run the command with **sudo**. Problem solved.

**Command-Example:** sudo ionic cordova platform add android

**OUTPUT:**

```
$ sudo ionic cordova platform add android
> cordova platform add android --save

You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~7.1.1
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
    Path: platforms/android
    Package: io.ionic.starter
    Name: MyApp
    Activity: MainActivity
    Android target: android-27
Android project created with cordova-android@7.1.4
Android Studio project detected
Android Studio project detected
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-whitelist" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

               This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

Adding cordova-plugin-whitelist to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-whitelist" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-statusbar" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-statusbar" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-statusbar to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-statusbar" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-device" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-device to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-device" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-splashscreen to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Adding cordova-plugin-ionic-webview to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" to config.xml
Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" for android
Adding cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard to package.json
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" to config.xml
--save flag or autosave detected
Saving android@~7.1.4 into config.xml file ...
> ionic cordova resources android --force
✔ Collecting resource configuration and source images - done!
✔ Filtering out image resources that do not need regeneration - done!
✔ Uploading source images to prepare for transformations: 2 / 2 complete - done!
✔ Generating platform resources: 18 / 18 complete - done!
✔ Modifying config.xml to add new image resources - done!
```

**System Description:**

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Ionic 4.5.0

Cordova 8.1.2

Node v8.14.0

Answer (score 1):

try to modify ..//config.xml header

```
<widget id="io.ionic.starter" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>MyApp</name>
<description>An awesome Ionic/Cordova app.</description>
<author email="hi@ionicframework.com" href="http://ionicframework.com/">Ionic Framework Team</author>
<content src="index.html" />
```

then run

```
ionic cordova platform add ios 
ionic cordova platform add android
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7LcEw.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FPdI.png]

Comment: After all the research, modifying config.xml made it work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.npm

sudo chown -R $USER:$GROUP ~/.config

And Check this all package are install or not:

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.2.0
Cordova CLI      : 7.0.1 
Ionic CLI        : 3.2.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.7
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.2.1
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.2.0
Cordova Platforms               : ios 4.4.0
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.3.0
```

System:

```
Node       : v6.10.3
OS         : macOS Sierra
Xcode      : Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002 
ios-deploy : 1.9.1 
ios-sim    : 5.0.13
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I had resolved this problem by using commands                                                                               cordova platform rm ios   and   cordova platform add ios --nofetch